# jQuery UI Resize with table and colspans

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, resize

I need to implement jQuery UI Resize effect to a table. My table has colspans and width equal to 100%. I can't resize my table's columns which contain days. Without colspan everything simply works fine. What can I do to correct this behaviour?

```
<table style="width: 100%">
    <tr>
        <th colspan="3">Table</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>26/12</th>
        <th>27/12</th>
        <th>28/12</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>123</td>
        <td>123</td>
        <td>123</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

```js
$(function () {
    $('table th').resizable({
        handles: 'e',
        minWidth: 18
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Helid/JvELx/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove `table-layout:fixed;` from your css class:

```
table, td, th {
    /*table-layout:fixed;*/
    overflow:hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/BlackSRC/JvELx/2/)

Comment: My table is much bigger than in first example. It looks like this http://jsfiddle.net/Helid/JvELx/3/
With table-layout:fixed I can resize first row but I can't resize subrows. Is there any way to fix that?

Comment: @Helid I think you can't resize subrows because the data your are showing had filled the cells already. perhaps if you have wider screen you can resize them too.