# How to make columns of datatables.js resizable with jQuery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datatables

I found a solution to resize table's columns in stackoverflow

[jQuery UI Resize with table and colspans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18812432/jquery-ui-resize-with-table-and-colspans)

I'm trying to apply it to a datatable that is populated using server side processing, but datatable doesn't allow change the column width.

I have tried this http://jsfiddle.net/BlackSRC/JvELx/2/

I have this simple datatable

```
<table id="datatable-1" class="table table-hover" style="width: 100%">
</table>
```

My datatable initialization is:

```js
$(table).DataTable({
 'lengthMenu': [[10, 25, 50, 100], [10, 25, 50, 100]],
 'ordering': false,
 'processing': true,
 'serverSide': true,
 'dom': 'Blfrtip',
 'ajax': {
  'url': 'ajax.php',
  'type': 'GET'
 },
 'columns':[
  {'data': 'id', 'title': 'Id'},
  {'data': 'A', 'title': 'A'},
  {'data': 'B', 'title': 'C'},
  {'data': 'C', 'title': 'D'},
  {'data': 'D', 'title': 'E'}
 ]
});
```

Anyone know how can resize column using datatables.js?

Comment: show us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set `autoWidth` option to `false` on your datatable

```
$(table).DataTable({
    'lengthMenu': [[10, 25, 50, 100], [10, 25, 50, 100]],
    'ordering': false,
    'processing': true,
    'serverSide': true,
    'autoWidth': false,
    'dom': 'Blfrtip',
    'ajax': {
        'url': 'ajax.php',
        'type': 'GET'
    },
    'columns':[
        {'data': 'id', 'title': 'Id'},
        {'data': 'A', 'title': 'A'},
        {'data': 'B', 'title': 'C'},
        {'data': 'C', 'title': 'D'},
        {'data': 'D', 'title': 'E'}
    ]
});
```

then add css

```
table {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see an issue. You do want to run `.DataTable()` first, then run `.resizable()`

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/ah67jopf/3/

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  $(".data").DataTable({
    'lengthMenu': [
      [10, 25, 50, 100],
      [10, 25, 50, 100]
    ],
    'ordering': false,
    'processing': true,
    'serverSide': true,
    'dom': 'Blfrtip',
    'ajax': {
      'url': 'ajax.php',
      'type': 'GET'
    },
    'columns': [{
      'data': 'id',
      'title': 'Id'
    }, {
      'data': 'A',
      'title': 'A'
    }, {
      'data': 'B',
      'title': 'C'
    }, {
      'data': 'C',
      'title': 'D'
    }, {
      'data': 'D',
      'title': 'E'
    }]
  });
  $('table th').resizable({
    handles: 'e',
    minWidth: 18,
    stop: function(e, ui) {
      $(this).width(ui.size.width);
    }
  });
});
```

**Updated**

In the Stop callback, you can set the new size of the `th` element.

Hope that helps.

Comment: This example work perfectly, is like my code, but mine is not working. I can see in the inspector that th width change, but in browser doesn't show the resize.

Comment: @omixam do you see any errors in console? How are libraries being loaded, what order, in the `<head>`?

Comment: Any error in console.I disabled all libraries the order is the following: css: datatables and than jquery-ui, for JS: jquery, jquery-ui, and datatable.

Comment: I would advise a different order: Jquery UI CSS, Datatable CSS, jQuery, jQuery UI, DataTable. Should work as you described. I assume you meant no errors appear in console?

Comment: I used the order that you suggest me, but the result is the same. There isn't errors in the console.

Comment: Well, the problem is that my columns fill more than the space availble.

Comment: @omixam I'm not sure how to assist further since I cannot see the data you're using, nor can I replicate the issue.

Comment: In your jsfiddle is like "table with colspan". Thanks anyway, If I arrive to any solution I'm going to try not forget share it.

Comment: The solution does not really make the column re-sizable at all, even in your jsfiddle.  It just adds the behavior where you can drag a column line to start resizing a column but as soon as you stop moving the mouse, it snaps back to the original size.

It does work as look as you set the AutoWidth property to false:
```'autoWidth': false,```