# R Shiny making DataTable columns manuallly resizable

Tags: r, shiny, datatables, dt, column-width

I would like to ask if it is possible to let the user manually adjust the column widths by clicking on the column and dragging it. If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with the [colResize](https://github.com/dhobi/datatables.colResize) plugin. Download the **js** file and the **css** file. In the code below, **path/to/colResize** is the path to the folder containing these two files. If you use an absolute path, you don't need **normalizePath**.

```r
library(DT)
library(htmltools)

dep <- htmlDependency(
  name = "colResize", 
  version = "1.6.1", 
  src = normalizePath("path/to/colResize"),
  script = "jquery.dataTables.colResize.js",
  stylesheet = "jquery.dataTables.colResize.css",
  all_files = FALSE
)

dat <- iris

dtable <- datatable(
  dat,
  options = list(
    colResize = list()
  )
) 

deps <- dtable$dependencies
deps <- c(deps, list(dep))
dtable$dependencies <- deps

dtable
```

[image]

Comment: This plugin doesn't work.

Comment: @Avraam The GIF proves it works...

Comment: no. U can see this example website based on this plugin: http://live.datatables.net/hafazixi/3/edit - it doesn't work even here. And in my attempt/practice - it also did not work correctly (as resizable in reactable).

This post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67916127/column-resize-for-users-with-dtdatatable shows smth that should work, but so far I can't figure out how to integrate it into on R...

Comment: @Avraam There's an issue with the latest version of the **datatables** library: <https://github.com/dhobi/datatables.colResize/issues/12>. Try to downgrade the **DT** package.

Comment: Strange --- when I try this example, resizing only works on the first column?

Comment: Update: at first I also wrongly thought it didn't work, but it does.

The example will only show a resizing cursor on the first column -- and resizing doesn't work when you click *exactly* on the column line, you need to click ever-so-slightly to the left of it.

And you need to make the CSS adjustment from the github link @Avraam posted in order to get the resizing symbols to get shown on all columns.  (Only modification is to put "cursor: col-resize !important")

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr: Perhaps because of an issue with the latest version of **datatables**, you need to adjust **jquery.dataTables.colResize** to

```css
table.dataTable thead th.dt-colresizable-hover {
  cursor: col-resize !important;
```

Otherwise the resizing cursor won't show up.