# jQuery Datatable react col re-sizing

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, react-native, datatables

I have a working jquery datatables react code sample here titled `working-datatable-react`:

https://codesandbox.io/s/working-datatable-react-0hnidp?file=/src/index.js

And I really want to implement the row-width reorder / mouse dragging feature seen in the chosen answer for this stack overflow question:

[Column resize for users with DT::datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67916127/column-resize-for-users-with-dtdatatable)

```
$(function() {
  $(".data").DataTable({
    'ordering': false,
    'dom': 'Blfrtip',
    'autoWidth': false,
  });
  $('table th').resizable({
    handles: 'e',
    stop: function(e, ui) {
      $(this).width(ui.size.width);
    }
  });

});
```

So I fork `working-datatable-react` as `working-datatable-react (forked) edit-width attempt` and try to add this custom editable width feature, but im not sure how to implement the part of the stackoverflow answer code that is:

```
$('table th').resizable({
    handles: 'e',
    stop: function(e, ui) {
      $(this).width(ui.size.width);
    }
  });
```

because in my codesandbox react implementation, I need to call jquery in a different way

```
    const $el = $(tableRef.current);
    const dataTable = $el.DataTable({
      dom: 'Blfrtip',
      data: dataSet,
```

**How can I combine this [datatable width editing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67916127/column-resize-for-users-with-dtdatatable) into my [react Table.js component](https://codesandbox.io/s/working-datatable-react-0hnidp?file=/src/index.js)?**

Comment: updated link https://codesandbox.io/s/working-datatable-react-0hnidp?file=/src/index.js @andrewJames ill update title too , its col re-sizing not row reordering