# columns of datatables resizable [jquery]

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, datatables, resizable

I want to manually resize a table column column.

search on Stack Overflow and tried

[How to make columns of datatables.js resizable with jQuery UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46964156/how-to-make-columns-of-datatables-js-resizable-with-jquery-ui/46966259) &
[jQuery UI Resize with table and colspans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18812432/jquery-ui-resize-with-table-and-colspans)

and google example, official documentation.

https://github.com/dobtco/jquery-resizable-columns &
http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/ah67jopf/3/

**my example code**

```
<table id="examTbl" class="table table-bordered table-hover table-sm dataTable dtr-inline" data-resizable="true">
<thead>
    <tr>
       <th><input type="checkbox" id="chkbox"></th>
       <th>1</th>
       <th>2</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
</table>

<style>
table, td, th {
    /*table-layout:fixed;*/
    overflow:hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
</style>
```

**DataTables setting**

```
var table_option = {
   processing: true,
   serverSide: true,
   searching: false,
   responsive: true,
   dom: "lfBtip",
   ajax: {
      url: '/get/textVal'
   },
   columns: [{
      data: 'null',
      defaultContent: "<input type='checkbox' class='chkbox'>",
   },
   { data: 'test1' },
   { data: 'test2' },
   ],
   autoWidth: false,
   drawCallback: function(settings) {
                
   $('table th').resizable({
     handles: 'e',
     minWidth: 18,
     stop: function(e, ui) {
     $(this).width(ui.size.width);
    }
  });
 }
}
```

Comment: no errors in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can add "resize" css property on your styles.

```html
<table id="examTbl" class="table table-bordered table-hover table-sm dataTable dtr-inline" data-resizable="true">
<thead>
    <tr>
       <th><input type="checkbox" id="chkbox"></th>
       <th>1</th>
       <th>2</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
</table>

<style>
table, td, th {
    /*table-layout:fixed;*/
    overflow:hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    resize:horizontal;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If I do as you said, only the row at the top of the table moves, and the rows containing the data below are the same. How to solve this?

Comment: Do you want the "resize" functionality to be in the header of the table, but not in the content?

Comment: Yes the form I want to make is like this example.
https://examples.bootstrap-table.com/#extensions/resizable.html
(Only the upper th can be adjusted, when th is adjusted, the lower rows are also adjusted)

Answer (score 1):

Edit:
Try adding "autoWidth:false" on your datatable settings:

```
var table_option = {
   processing: true,
   serverSide: true,
   searching: false,
   autoWidth: false,
   responsive: true,
   dom: "lfBtip",
   ajax: {
      url: '/get/textVal'
   },
   columns: [{
      data: 'null',
      defaultContent: "<input type='checkbox' class='chkbox'>",
   },
   { data: 'test1' },
   { data: 'test2' },
   ],
   autoWidth: false,
   drawCallback: function(settings) {
                
   $('table th').resizable({
     handles: 'e',
     minWidth: 18,
     stop: function(e, ui) {
     $(this).width(ui.size.width);
    }
  });
 }
}
```

Solved in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/ah67jopf/3/